# Adding height with jquery to a div with !important in css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I’m making a button that adds to the height of a div, but since I’m making some responsive styles I have in the style sheet the height with !important and after I press the button, the height it’s not adding.

Here’s my code:

```
$("#mailDiv").height("+=70");
```

style:

```
#mailDiv{height: 300px !important;}
```

I hope you guys can help me

Comment: Using `!important` is rarely a good idea.  I would suggest redesigning that part to not use `!important`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `.attr` then add style attribute and add your extra height like this to style attribute :

```
"height:"+($("#mydiv").height()+extra)+'px!important'
```

you can see demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yx0pqcuL/)

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
$("#mailDiv").attr('style', 'height: ' + parseInt($("#mailDiv").height() + 70) +'px !important;')
```

**See JSFiddle to see in action: http://jsfiddle.net/kbf7s20r/**